# Вытащить нужные слова из списка

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список,

```
answer = ['F1. Бла бла бла',
          'F2. Бла бла бла',
          'F3. Бла бла бла',
          'F4. Бла бла бла']
```

и мне надо сделать так, чтобы вытаскивал только F1 и другие F (их может быть больше и меньше 4)

```
yy = ''
yy = yy.join(answer)
print(yy.split('.'))
```

когда я пытаюсь так отделить, выходит вот так:

```
['F1', ' Бла бла блаF2', ' Бла бла блаF3', ' Бла бла блаF4', ' Бла бла бла']
```

а мне надо, чтобы выходило так :

```
['F1','F2','F3','F4']
```

как можно такое реализовать на Python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо строки объединять, работайте с теми, что есть:

```py
result = [x.split('.')[0] for x in answer]
# ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4']
```